# How do I guarantee node order for an XPath 'OR' query

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have a snippet of XML that looks like

```
<body>
   Some text....
   <nodeA>....</nodeA>
   more text
   <someOtherNode>
      <nodeA>.......</nodeA>
   </someOtherNode>
   <nodeB>.......</nodeB>  
   etc.....
</body>
```

I'm selecting all nodeA and NodeB nodes inside `<body>` using an XPATH query similar to
`//nodeA|//nodeB`

As I understand it, .NET supports XPath 1.0 which does not guarantee node order.

How can I guarantee selected nodes are returned in document order in my OR query : that's to say:

```
nodeA, nodeA, nodeB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As I understand it, .NET supports
>   XPath 1.0 which does not guarantee
>   node order

When an XPath 1.0 expression that selects nodes is evaluated, the selected nodes form a *node-set*. **A node-set is a set and this, among many other things, means that it is unordered**.

**For practical purposes, though, there is one main ordering** chosen to enumerate the nodes of a node set: document order. In practice, all XPath 1.0 engines I know (and certainly in .NET) return the selected nodes in document order. In the future this is unlikely to change, because vendors try to preserve backwards compatibility.

**Therefore, just try using the `SelectNodes()` or `Evaluate()` methods and verify that the nodes in the results are in document order**.

**Do note**: The order of the following cannot be guaranteed and is implementation-dependent:

1. Attributes of the same element.
2. Nodes belonging to different documents (a node-set containing nodes from different documents can be produced using the XSLT function `document()`, so this most probably is of no concern to you).

Comment: That's how I understand it too, but I haven't yet found an *official* reference that confirms this behaviour for SelectNodes() as implemented by .NET when there's an OR (union) operator in the XPath

Comment: @Tom-Carter: A union expression (BTW this isn't the same as a boolean expression using the `or` operator) is just a normal XPath expression. Why do you need a separate statement for the order of nodes just for a union expression?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the nodes outside of XPath. So iterate through the nodes in the node-set and add them to a collection, which you then sort using `XPathNavigator.ComparePosition` for comparisons.

Either that or use an XPath 2.0 implementation for .NET